# How to do default property explicit interface in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, properties, interface, default, explicit

I have been trying to figure out how to do

```
object IList.this[int index]
{
    get { }
    set { }
}

public T this[int index]
{
    get { }
    set { }
}
```

In VB.net, and I have not been able to find anything on google.

Just to clarify, I am trying to implement the default property defined in 2 different interfaces.

Thanks :)

Comment: Im actually suspecting that this cant be done in VB.net.

Answer (score 1):

The VB.NET IDE will auto-generate the implementation methods as soon as you press the Enter key after typing the `Implements IFoo(Of T)` statement.  Producing:

```
Default Public Property Item(index As Integer) As T Implements IFoo(Of T).Item
    '' Get and Set...
End Property

Private Property IList_Item(index As Integer) As T Implements IList(Of T).Item
    '' Get and Set...
End Property
```

I had to guess at IFoo since your snippet isn't complete enough, substitute yours.  It does flub on the IList.Item implementation, you have to remove the Default keyword since a class can have only one Default property (aka "indexer").  Note that in VB.NET, all interface method implementations are explicit, presumably the speed-bump.  And that "Item" is the name of the indexer.

Comment: Ohh, ehm the one interface does not have an generic footprint, so only one of them has Of T, like IList(Of T) and IList.

Comment: I'm trying to think of a reason why you would hide your code and intentionally post a shoddy snippet.  As hard as I try, I can't think of one.

Comment: I wasn't trying to hide my code, I was only trying to display the relevant code parts, note that the difference in the 2 properties are the type and the explicit identifier. so not to bloat the post with unrelated code.

Comment: besides the culprit is the Default Property, since both interfaces defines a default property, vb.net complains when trying to explicitly address the 2 different default properties, which c# has no issues with.